# 1st PC irregular in Supervised Principal Component Analysis

Tags: r, principal-components

I am using superpc package to carry out supervised principal component analysis on my data.
I am using the following link as reference

http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/superpc/tutorial

I am using regression analysis for my data.

When I plot the CVPlot, I get the following plot

[image]

As per my understanding the likelihood statistic ratio should be highest for 3rd analysis and so should be the threshold value. However I am getting an irregular plot.
Can someone guide if I have interpreted it correctly or not. And due to what reasons can the graph be irregular?

Comment: Probably more a statistics question than a programming one. Voted for migration to SE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will post it in SE. Can I directly move it to SE from here?